# Azure DevOps az cli log in as user from pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, azure-cli

I am trying to create a pipeline in which I'll run terraform configs against an Azure subscription from Azure DevOps pipelines. All works fine, but when I am trying to log in as user with az cli it fails with:

```
ERROR: Authentication failed due to error of 'Unsupported wstrust endpoint version. Current support version is wstrust2005 or wstrust13.' This typically happens when attempting a Microsoft account, which requires interactive login. Please invoke 'az login' to cross check. More details are available at https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/wiki/Username-Password-Authentication
ERROR: Please run 'az login' to setup account.
```

Although from cli on my local it works to do `az log in -u user -p pass`

Command was executed from a script, because after log in I'll move to terraform commands which requires those creds:

```
      - script: |
          az login -u $(u) -p $(p)
          terraform init
          terraform plan
```

I know it's not a best practice to use an user instead of a service principal, but for now I have to stick with this method. So is there a way to automate az login from Azure DevOps pipelines?

Answer (score 3):

```
az login -u $(secretUser) -p $(secretPassword)
```

Put the user ID and password into Azure Key Vault, named `secretUser` and `secretPassword`, and then use the `AzureKeyVault@1` task to populate it

```
  - task: AzureKeyVault@1
    inputs:
      ConnectedServiceName: Your Service Connection Name
      KeyVaultName: Your Key Vault Name
      SecretsFilter: 'secretUser,secretPassword'
      RunAsPreJob: true 
  - script: |
      az login -u $(secretUser) -p $(secretPassword)
      terraform init
      terraform plan
```

Comment: Another reason of not using SPs, is that I don't have their passwords and as far as I know  those aren't stored somewhere. Also one more requirement is that an SP shouldn't let create other SPs, that is way I have to stick to users  creds.

Comment: I've altered my answer to hopefully better suit your need.

Comment: Thanks for getting back with solutions. The thing is that this is actually my initial setup, I already had my keys in vaults and I was invoking `script` with az login, but it fails with the error described in the question ```ERROR: Please run 'az login' to setup account.
```

Comment: If I understand your comment correctly, you're saying that you can't get to the Key Vault because you can't log in? If so, the AzureKeyVault@1 task relies on a service connection, that's already authenticated by service principal - if you place this before the task that needs the variables, it should have access. In other words, the task is using a different way to connect that doesn't rely on az login.

Comment: In order to run terraform I need a user to authenticate with `azcli` directly into the pipeline. For that I invoke `script` task with: az login then terraform commands. Az login takes creds from the key vault. 
Now my problem is specifically on the point where azcli is logging in, it fails with the error from the original question.

Comment: If the user ID you're using is a Microsoft account (or presumably an Azure AD account), this will happen, as an interactive login is required. Could you explain more about why a user ID is required? I know that you don't want an SP to create another SP, but if the access scope on the SP you use here is limited enough (that is, you're not enabling administrator on the subscription, for example) you should be able to get a little closer to a least-privilege model?

Answer (score 3):

The [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli) task can be used instead of the Script task

It works like the normal script tasks and you select what scripting language you want to run with the `scriptType`property:

> Type of script: PowerShell/PowerShell Core/Bat/Shell script. Select
> bash/pscore script when running on Linux agent or batch/ps/pscore
> script when running on Windows agent. PowerShell Core script can run
> on cross-platform agents (Linux, macOS, or Windows)

It also takes a service connection reference in the `azureSubscription` input. The service connection should be of type Azure Resource Manager and can be created either [automatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/connect-to-azure?view=azure-devops#create-an-azure-resource-manager-service-connection-using-automated-security) or by using an [existing service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/connect-to-azure?view=azure-devops#create-an-azure-resource-manager-service-connection-with-an-existing-service-principal).

The azure connection details are safely stored in the service connection and when your script starts executing Azure CLI has already been logged in using the service connection

Below is an example of how your pipeline task would look

```yaml
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: Azure CLI
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: <Name of the Azure Resource Manager service connection>
    scriptType: bash
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
      terraform init
      terraform plan
```